# Differences between different types of rust Vectors containing pointers

Tags: pointers, rust, reference, borrow-checker

Essentially, I wanted to know the exact difference between

```
* Vec<usize>
* Vec<&usize>
* Vec<&mut usize>
* Vec<&mut &usize>
```

Specifically the last one

Comment: The distinction has nothing to do with `Vec`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `Vec<usize>` - a vector containing `usize` numbers
- `Vec<&usize>` - a vector containing references to `usize` numbers that are stored somewhere else
- `Vec<&mut usize>` - same as `Vec<&usize>`, but the referenced `usize` numbers can be modified
- `Vec<&mut &usize>` - a vector containing references that point to other references that point to `usize`. The referenced references can be modified, but the `usize` numbers can not.

**Additional remarks:**

- `Vec<&usize>` is pointless. A `&usize` can only be used to access the values read-only, and everything that it can do can be done more efficiently with a `Vec<usize>`. For primitive types like `usize`, passing by-value is usually faster than by-reference for non-mutable access.
- `Vec<&mut &usize>` is very exotic and probably won't ever be encountered in real code.

Comment: I guess for completeness' sake, we can also throw in `Vec<&mut &mut usize>`. A vector containing references that point to other references that point to `usize`. The referenced references can be modified, as can the `usize` numbers.

Comment: @cadolphs There are infinitely more if you want completeness. However, for real projects, `Vec<usize>` and `Vec<&mut usize>` are probably the only two that matter. Although even that might be a stretch; realistically you will encounter `Vec<usize>`, `&mut Vec<usize>` and `&[usize]`. Maybe in rare cases `&mut [usize]`.